# Convert TestObject to List<WebElement> and pass it as arguments

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, groovy, katalon-studio

I have a method and I want to pass a List as an argument but I suppose I need to pass TestObject in Katalon, so how do I convert that TestObject to List in Katalon

```
public void selectDropdown(List<WebElement> ele, String value) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) {

            String option = ele.get(i).getText();
            if (option.contains(value)) {

                ele.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
            Thread.sleep(500);
        }
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
```

So I think I need to pass TestObject in place of List but how do I then convert that test object in to a List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I eventually did it.

```
@Keyword
def selectDropdown(TestObject Obj, String Value)
{
   List<WebElement> ele = WebUiCommonHelper.findWebElements(Obj, 20);

   for (int i = 0; i < ele.size(); i++) 
   {
       String option = ele.get(i).getText();
       if (option.contains(value)) 
       {
          ele.get(i).click();
          break;
       }
       Thread.sleep(500);
   }
   Thread.sleep(500);
}
```